# About certain overlapping tags for [transportation]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

About certain overlapping tags for [transportation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation)?

This list is: tag, question count, followed by excerpt.

- [infrastructure](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure) 32
  Use this tag in reference to the structures and systems that sustain large portions of the population such as highways, bridges, the electrical power grid, etc.
- [transportation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation) 26
  Questions involving the politics of means of transport, affecting automobiles, boats, trains, planes, as well as roads, railroad tracks, etc.
- [railroad](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railroad) 7
  Use for questions about political issues directly related to railroads, such as their funding, regulation, or development and promotion by a government.
- [public-transport](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-transport) 4
  The public-transport tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

**Overlaps:**

[transportation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation) contains elements of [infrastructure](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure). Roads/Highways, bridges, airports, etc., could fall into both.

[railroad](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railroad) contains elements of [transportation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation) and [public-transport](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-transport); for the latter, public transportation by rail.

Comment: In how many cases is it actually a problem to have both tags if they're both relevant? As long as there aren't other more relevant tags that can't be added because of the 5-tag limit, I don't think it's a problem to have both [transportation] and [infrastructure] tags on the same question. The railroad tag may be too specific, but I'm not sure about the [public-transport].

Comment: Approximately 14% (864) of [united-states] tagged questions have 5 tags, I think these are mostly due to over-tagging. My "go-to" thinking is to minimize the use of tags wherever possible. It may not be a problem. I just want to reduce the potential. I would not remove one of the tags, if both were present and no other tag was needed; or add the other, if I found an unexpected question were both were appropriate.

Comment: @RickSmith Why is fewer tags better? People follow tags, so the more tags, the more people that might be able to answer the question might get pinged.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- yea, I thought the same thing at first. Looking at it again though, a question about trains may be tagged [railroad], [transportation] and [public-transport]. If there are three more relevant tags then one must be dropped. Keeping all these specific tags risks scattering similar question topics across different tags, thus reducing findability.

Comment: This has been featured for over a week now with no downvotes on the question or answer. Do you think it's time to go ahead with merging or are you still reviewing some of these questions?

Comment: @JJJ For the purpose of making [railroad] and [public-transport] synonyms of [transportation], I am OK with going ahead. There are questions that could use changes other than the two synonyms, I will revisit those by reviewing all [transportation] questions after the merge.

Comment: Okay, I've created the synonym and merged them. Shall I mark this question as [status-completed] or do you think it needs more attention from others?

Comment: @JJJ - I think [status-completed] is fine, given that others have had a month to comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest making [railroad](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railroad) and [public-transport](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-transport) synonyms of [transportation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation).

The "common sense" solution for the infrastructure overlap is:

If an infrastructure question involves transportation elements only, use the [transportation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation) tag.

Otherwise, use the [infrastructure](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure) tag.

I can see no reason to use both.

But, note that, currently, 5 questions use both [railroad](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railroad) and [infrastructure](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure). This would conflict with not using both. Removing [infrastructure](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infrastructure) from those questions would resolve the conflict. ([See the list.](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/railroad+infrastructure))

One question uses [transportation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transportation) and [public-transport](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-transport): [What is the capitalist answer to rail passenger transportation being non financially profitable?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/33937/26455), and may need the [public-transport](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-transport) tag removed.

Comment: "railroad" is not synonymous with "public-transport," it would be pretty easy to ask a question about freight rail that is not public whatsoever.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I'm suggesting that [public-transport] is a synonym of [transportation] and that [railroad] is also a synonym of [transportation].

Comment: Hm, yeah, fair enough